# Workaround for not losing cell's reference because of user doing sorting, while script checks cells value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been struggling with the following situation for almost the whole last week and it would be awesome if someone could give me some hint.

The situation:
1. Script finds a particular value in, lets say, 'Sheet1', and gets the row number of the cell containing this value.
2. Since script has found this value, it executes a bunch of actions like creating new spreadsheet and copying numerous 'Sheet1' from dozen other spreadsheets to this newly created spreadsheet, and comparing/ analyzing data.

The problem.
- While script is doing a bunch of other actions, user is able to rearrange cells by, for example, sorting A to Z, which changes the address of previously found cell.

Here is the code that I used in order to verify this:

```
function WhatHappensIfUserSorts () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rng = sh.getRange("B17"); //Lets say that script finds this cell according to some rules
  Utilities.sleep(10000);
  rng.setValue("Test Value");
}
```

Question:
Might there be any workaround for this?

My current ideas.
1. I was thinking about hiding the filter row in the beginning of the script, but this doesn't help a lot, because users can insert new row in the which will change the addresses of the rows below.

The background.
I am trying to create two way synchronization, meaning, each project member has his/ her own spreadsheet with 'Project X', 'Project Y' etc. sheets and no matter who updates their project sheets, all other users that work on the same project get these updates in their project sheets. These updates that have to be tracked are not just the cell values, these are cell notes as well. And this is the reason why script has to do the bunch of other actions, since CopyTo method does not work between spreadsheets.

During my research I found [sheetSpider](https://sites.google.com/site/heroscripts/course-feedback/sheetspider) project, but it seems somewhat different and too complicated from what I need.

Answer (score 1):

A simple suggestion would be to give each row a unique identifier so that you could use it to evaluate the target range again before you write back to the sheet.

get target row's unique ID --> do work --> locate target rows ID and use to determine write range --> write back to sheet.

Alternatively, during the operation you could delete the target row and then use appendRow() to drop the updated version back in.

A third and final suggestion might be to temporarily suspend the permissions for the sheet. See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/page-protection#setProtected